# Snowflake task scheduling

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to write a snowflake task to run everyday at every 2 minutes from 5:00 EST to 5:00 PM EST.
The code I wrote is not working, the task didnt stop running even after 5:00 PM:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK tsk_master
    WAREHOUSE = XS_WH
    SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON * 5-17 * * * America/New_York'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
COMMENT = 'Master task job to trigger all other tasks'
AS call pntinsight_lnd.SP_ACCT_DIM_1();
```

Please suggest what did I do wrong, how to stop it from running after 5 PM, and how can i set it to run every 2 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define all trigger minutes, it looks ugly but it should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK tsk_master
    WAREHOUSE = XS_WH
    SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58  5-17 * * * America/New_York'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
COMMENT = 'Master task job to trigger all other tasks'
AS call pntinsight_lnd.SP_ACCT_DIM_1();
```

Comment: To query the current usage for all serverless tasks, execute the following statement with ACCOUNTADMIN as the active role in the session:


select start_time, end_time, task_id, task_name, credits_used, schema_id, schema_name, database_id, database_name
  from snowflake.account_usage.serverless_task_history
  order by start_time, task_id;

Answer (score 1):

> *snowflake task to run everyday at every 2 minutes from 5:00 EST to 5:00 PM EST.*

[Optional parameters:](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#optional-parameters)

> **/n**
>
> **Indicates the nth instance of a given unit of time.** Each quanta of time is computed independently

So every 2 minutes will be:

```
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON */2 5-17 * * * America/New_York'
```